# JavaScript redirect to a website works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku

I have an app that redirects to a website using

```
window.location.href = "https://example.com"
```

This works locally and also redirects after the app is deployed to Heroku. However, when I try it after deploying on the Heroku website, the app redirects to the same url but I get a cloudfare error 520, which probably has to do with the site I want to redirect it to. After a few seconds, if I refresh the redirected page, the cloudfare error is gone and the page loads normally. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: Check if this can help you: https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-520-web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error/44205

Comment: This doesn't sound like a problem you can do anything about (unless you own `example.com`).